# ion-input not rendering in ionic1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am started working on Ionic 1 application and new to Ionic Framework. I want to create ionic specific input fields using , tag but this tag is not rendering in ionic 1.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

label is creating and input fields not created. When I tried same tag in Ionic3, it is working working.
My requirement is  tag make to work in ionic 1.

Please help me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can't use ion-input with ionic 1 because ver. 1 use standard input tag. Maybe the solution is to create custom ion-input component.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#forms

Comment: Thank you Marko Savic for giving reply. This is fine and is there any other way to make exact ion-input type fields in version1 using third party files.